# Se pueden recorrer los elementos de values / color.xml en android?

Tags: android

Me gustaría saber si es posible el acceder a los elementos declarados dentro de values / color con algún comodín, me explico...

Si quiero que me aparezca de una forma aleatoria alguno de los colores que tengo declarados en mi colors.xml, de que forma podría acceder a ellos sin poner "n" cantidad de ifs?

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#384046</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#384046</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#384046</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

<!--Color red-->
<color name="red50">#ffebee</color>
<color name="red100">#ffcdd2</color>
<color name="red200">#ef9a9a</color>
<color name="red300">#e57373</color>
<color name="red400">#ef5350</color>
<color name="red500">#f44336</color>
<color name="red600">#e53935</color>
<color name="red700">#d32f2f</color>
<color name="red800">#c62828</color>
<color name="red900">#b71c1c</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

En `values / colors.xml` creamos los diferentes colores rojos y creamos un array para luego poder acceder a ellos.

```
<!--Color red-->
    <color name="red50">#ffebee</color>
    <color name="red100">#ffcdd2</color>
    <color name="red200">#ef9a9a</color>
    <color name="red300">#e57373</color>
    <color name="red400">#ef5350</color>
    <color name="red500">#f44336</color>
    <color name="red600">#e53935</color>
    <color name="red700">#d32f2f</color>
    <color name="red800">#c62828</color>
    <color name="red900">#b71c1c</color>

    <array name="rojos_varios">
        <item>@color/red50</item>
        <item>@color/red100</item>
        <item>@color/red200</item>
        <item>@color/red300</item>
        <item>@color/red400</item>
        <item>@color/red500</item>
        <item>@color/red600</item>
        <item>@color/red700</item>
        <item>@color/red800</item>
        <item>@color/red900</item>
    </array>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora para recuperar ese array desde código, tendríamos que hacer algo como esto..

```
int[] rojosVarios = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.rojos_varios);
```

Ahora crearíamos un generador de números aleatorios con el rango de nuestro array..

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = rnd.nextInt(rojosVarios.length);
```

Y ya sería establecer ese color en un texto por ejemplo:

```
texto.setTextColor(rojosVarios[num]);
```

---

Te dejo un ejemplo completo.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="Cambiar Color letra"
        android:onClick="cambiarColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView texto;
    int[] rojosVarios;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rojosVarios = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.rojos_varios);

        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }


    public void cambiarColor(View view) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.nextInt(rojosVarios.length);
        texto.setTextColor(rojosVarios[num]);
    }
}
```

---

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

> Me gustaría saber si es posible el acceder a los elementos declarados
>   dentro de values / color con algún comodín, me explico...

**No, el acceso al elemento se debe realizar mediante el id del elemento.**

Si deseas obtener un color aleatorio deberás realizar un método para obtener un valor aleatorio de estos colores, en el cual debes definir todos los ids,  por ejemplo el siguiente método el cual obtiene un valor entero del color .

```
public int getRandomColor() {
    //Define el array de colores almacenados en colors.xml.
    int[] colores = {R.color.red50, R.color.red100, R.color.red200, R.color.red300, R.color.red400, R.color.red500, R.color.red600, R.color.red700, R.color.red800, R.color.red900};
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.nextInt(colores.length);
    return getResources().getColor(colores[num]);
}
```

El anterior método lo puedes usar para obtener el color y usarlo en varios métodos como [**setColor(** getRandomColor() **)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(int)), [**setBackgroundColor(** getRandomColor() **)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundColor(int)) o [**setTextColor(** getRandomColor() **)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextColor(int))

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.